# Getting redirect URL from links with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, puppeteer

I have a JSON array and I need to update them by looping through, based on a Puppeteer function. After some iteration, the Puppeteer function does not work. It gets me the wrong URL.

For test purposes, I tried to run just one object and the function worked well (getting the right URL).

Do you guess some path to make it work properly?

I call this function to iterate on JSON to update each link.

```js
async function iterateToUpdateLinks(jsonArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        jsonArray[i].link = await urlUpdate(jsonArray[i].link)
    }
    return jsonArray
}
```

JSON Array used to iterate.

```
[
  {'title': 'abc', 'link':'https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEHxSZ7LBmHeDe2YaolWN_CAqFwgEKg8IACoHCAowjuuKAzCWrzwwt4QY?uo=CAUiSGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm55dGltZXMuY29tLzIwMjIvMTAvMjMvbnlyZWdpb24vbWlncmFudHMtbnljLWVyaWMtYWRhbXMuaHRtbNIBAA&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'},
  {'title': 'def', 'link':'https://news.google.com/articles/CBMifmh0dHBzOi8vdHlsZXJwYXBlci5jb20vbGlmZXN0eWxlL2hlYWx0aC9hZ2UtbWF0dGVycy1mb3ItdXNlLW9mLWF0LWhvbWUtdGVzdHMvYXJ0aWNsZV85NzUwYTRjZS1iZTFhLTVkNTgtYmRlMC00OGU5MTk2NWIwMmIuaHRtbNIBggFodHRwczovL3R5bGVycGFwZXIuY29tL2xpZmVzdHlsZS9oZWFsdGgvYWdlLW1hdHRlcnMtZm9yLXVzZS1vZi1hdC1ob21lLXRlc3RzL2FydGljbGVfOTc1MGE0Y2UtYmUxYS01ZDU4LWJkZTAtNDhlOTE5NjViMDJiLmFtcC5odG1s?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'},
  {'title': 'ghi', 'link':'https://news.google.com/articles/CBMie2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNvbW1lcmNpYWxhcHBlYWwuY29tL3N0b3J5L25ld3MvMjAyMi8xMC8yMy9zdGFkaXVtLXJlcXVlc3QtZm9yLW1lbXBoaXMtYS10ZXN0LW9mLXN0cmlja2xhbmRzLWJvbmRzLzY5NTcyMjgyMDA3L9IBAA?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen'}
]
```

Puppeteer Function

```js
async function urlUpdate(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.setRequestInterception(true)
    page.setDefaultTimeout(6000)

    page.on('request', (request) => {
    // IF STATEMENT TO GET URL OF URL REDIRECT
    if (request.resourceType() === 'document' && request.url() !== url) {
            url = request.url()
        } 
        request.continue()
    })

    try {
        await page.goto(url,{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    } finally {
        await browser.close()
        return url
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're trying to accomplish but the request handler seems odd--it shouldn't be assigning a global. Please provide a complete, runnable [mcve] rather than a bunch of tiny code snippets that I need to piece together. Thanks.

Comment: I am away from computer now. But, this is the exact code that I run. I call iterate function with Json as an arg and store in another const.

Comment: @ggorlen i've updated this question. I hope it's enough.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks, but the end result is still unclear. Why are you doing this? The code pattern here is bizarre and brittle so it's a likely [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). There should be a much clearer and more reliable way to achieve whatever end goal you're trying to achieve if more context could be provided.

Comment: @ggorlen Alright, I have a pool of links (masked/crypto) from google news and I need to get the redirect link. I am not a programmer, so it's a bad code. I know that, but i am trying to solve this problem. 

After getting this redirect links i'll use to send by e-mail to interested people about some matters.

Comment: OK, makes sense. After `goto(urlThatWillRedirect, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})`, then can you simply do `await page.url()` to get the URL? Or you can `waitForRequest` using the same condition you have here, which might be a bit faster. I'd probably make one browser and reuse it, possibly also reusing pages as well. The current approach appears to be a race condition and doesn't de-register the listener, so even after you've gotten the request URL you might overwrite it with another one. Also, it's more code.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. I will readjust to use just one browser. I don't know how to use wait functions well. But I will try to adjust to your suggestion tomorrow and I'll notice the sucess status here. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer seems like overkill here. I'd just use Cheerio and fetch (native in Node 18+) or axios:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const data = [
  {
    title: "abc",
    link: "https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEHxSZ7LBmHeDe2YaolWN_CAqFwgEKg8IACoHCAowjuuKAzCWrzwwt4QY?uo=CAUiSGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm55dGltZXMuY29tLzIwMjIvMTAvMjMvbnlyZWdpb24vbWlncmFudHMtbnljLWVyaWMtYWRhbXMuaHRtbNIBAA&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen",
  },
  {
    title: "def",
    link: "https://news.google.com/articles/CBMifmh0dHBzOi8vdHlsZXJwYXBlci5jb20vbGlmZXN0eWxlL2hlYWx0aC9hZ2UtbWF0dGVycy1mb3ItdXNlLW9mLWF0LWhvbWUtdGVzdHMvYXJ0aWNsZV85NzUwYTRjZS1iZTFhLTVkNTgtYmRlMC00OGU5MTk2NWIwMmIuaHRtbNIBggFodHRwczovL3R5bGVycGFwZXIuY29tL2xpZmVzdHlsZS9oZWFsdGgvYWdlLW1hdHRlcnMtZm9yLXVzZS1vZi1hdC1ob21lLXRlc3RzL2FydGljbGVfOTc1MGE0Y2UtYmUxYS01ZDU4LWJkZTAtNDhlOTE5NjViMDJiLmFtcC5odG1s?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen",
  },
  {
    title: "ghi",
    link: "https://news.google.com/articles/CBMie2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNvbW1lcmNpYWxhcHBlYWwuY29tL3N0b3J5L25ld3MvMjAyMi8xMC8yMy9zdGFkaXVtLXJlcXVlc3QtZm9yLW1lbXBoaXMtYS10ZXN0LW9mLXN0cmlja2xhbmRzLWJvbmRzLzY5NTcyMjgyMDA3L9IBAA?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen",
  },
];

(async () => {
  for (const item of data) {
    const response = await fetch(item.link);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }

    const $ = cheerio.load(await response.text());
    item.link = $('a[rel="nofollow"]').attr("href");
    // or: item.link = $('[jsname="tljFtd"]').text();
  }

  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    title: 'abc',
    link: 'https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/23/nyregion/migrants-nyc-eric-adams.html'
  },
  {
    title: 'def',
    link: 'https://tylerpaper.com/lifestyle/health/age-matters-for-use-of-at-home-tests/article_9750a4ce-be1a-5d58-bde0-48e91965b02b.html'
  },
  {
    title: 'ghi',
    link: 'https://www.commercialappeal.com/story/news/2022/10/23/stadium-request-for-memphis-a-test-of-stricklands-bonds/69572282007/'
  }
]
```

If you do need to use Puppeteer, the same general approach works:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

const data = [/* same as above */];

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  for (const item of data) {
    const intercept = req =>
      req.url() === item.link ? req.continue() : req.abort();

    page.on("request", intercept);
    await page.goto(item.link, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    item.link = await page.$eval('a[rel="nofollow"]', el => el.href);
    page.off("request", intercept);
  }

  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

This will be slower than fetch/cheerio but may be needed to bypass blocks (try a user agent on the fetch first).